# Need to replace motor, how can I remove the circuit board intact? If I can't, where can I get a new one?

Tags: pcb, motor, soldering

I am unsure how it is attached or how to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried desoldering the terminals to see if the assembly comes apart cleanly? The PCB doesn't seem too intricate, just some capacitors to suppress noise, which you could attach manually if you purchased the same caps with leads.

Comment: no i haven't, i will give that a try thanks.

Comment: why do you need to replace the motor?

Comment: because it is broken, does not move the tires anymore after some solder broke off of the inside

Comment: Most likely the attachment is simply the solder to the motor's terminals. Clean that off, straighten the terminals, and the PCB may come off intact. There is most likely a 3rd wire at the back connected to the motor's case. This is the classic capacitor delta to reduce commutator RF interference.

Comment: That PCB was either made by incompetent people or it has been exposed to extreme heat. The capacitors are up in the air, see? Also the wires appear to have cold joints. I wouldn't try to salvage this, it's a quack job from the start.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the picture what may actually be securing that PCB to the motor, but if I had to guess some sort of epoxy or glue.  Without knowing exactly what type of adhesive you won't really be able to know what solvent to use to get rid of it but if it's a relatively inexpensive motor then you could probably remove it with heat and some light prying, either with a heatgun or a hair-dryer can work in a pinch.

Is there any particular reason you are attempting to keep the controller board, it just looks like it has +V/-V and some small decoupling capacitors and probably comes as part of the motor assembly if you were to just purchase a new one.

Comment: i just dont know how to set up a new onw or where to get one

Comment: If you end up getting a new motor as a replacement (there are likely some markings e.g. part number printed on the body of the motor, or a sticker) then the new motor will most likely contain this PCB as well which means you wouldn't have to remove this one.  Was the PCB in your picture already attached to that motor when you first got it?

Comment: came as part of a RC car, so i don't know. have desoldered it off now and it is in a good condition so all is good#